# Cómo puedo optimizar esta consulta SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimización

Saludos a la comunidad.

Sé que hay varias preguntas con el mismo título, sin embargo, aclaro que esta es individual y diferente.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```sql
WHILE @contadorG <= @TrabajadoresQ BEGIN 
    
    SET @SumaTotal = (
        SELECT SUM(TSEC.haber)*-1
        FROM @TSaldoEmisionCliente TSEC
        WHERE TSEC.indiceCliente = @contadorG ) -- AND TSEC.saldo<0 

    IF(@SumaTotal IS NULL) BEGIN 
        SET @SumaTotal = 0
    END

    SELECT @CantidadFilas = COUNT(*)
    FROM @TSaldoEmisionCliente TSEC
    WHERE TSEC.debe >= 0 AND TSEC.indiceCliente = @contadorG 


    IF(@CantidadFilas = 0 ) BEGIN  
        SELECT  TOP (1) @saldoActual = ST.haber, @clienteActual = ST.cliente, @emisionActual = ST.emision
        FROM @TSaldoEmisionCliente ST 
        WHERE ST.indiceCliente = @contadorG
        ORDER BY ST.emision DESC
        
        INSERT INTO @resultadoTabla (indiceCliente, cliente , emision, IoE, saldo_a_restar, diferenciaResultante) 
        VALUES (@contadorG, @clienteActual , @emisionActual , @saldoActual , @saldoActual, @SumaTotal)  
    END

    SET @contadorF = 1

    WHILE @contadorF <= @CantidadFilas BEGIN 
        
        IF EXISTS (
            SELECT * 
            FROM @TSaldoEmisionCliente 
            WHERE debe >= 0  AND indiceCliente = @contadorG AND indice = @contadorF) BEGIN

                SELECT  @saldoActual = ST.debe, 
                        @clienteActual = ST.cliente, 
                        @emisionActual = ST.emision
                FROM @TSaldoEmisionCliente ST 
                WHERE ST.debe >= 0  AND ST.indiceCliente = @contadorG AND ST.indice = @contadorF 
                ORDER BY ST.emision ASC

                INSERT INTO @resultadoTabla (indiceCliente, cliente , emision, IoE, saldo_a_restar, diferenciaResultante) 
                VALUES (@contadorG, @clienteActual , @emisionActual , @saldoActual , @SumaTotal, @SumaTotal +@saldoActual)

                SET @contadorF = @contadorF + 1
                SET @SumaTotal = @SumaTotal + @saldoActual
        END

        ELSE BEGIN 
            SET @contadorF = @contadorF +1
            SET @CantidadFilas = @CantidadFilas + 1
        END

    END

    SET @contadorG = @contadorG + 1

END
```

Funciona perfecto, lo que pasa es que tengo una base de datos con más de 100 mil registros aproximadamente y lo que hace esta consulta es hacer un cálculo interno para arrojar un resultado final por persona.

Esta consulta es parte de un procedimiento almacenado y que probado con todas las demás consultas internas y esta es la causante del retraso, se tarda poco más de 7 min en ejecutarse por completo.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hace falta información, en que parte llenas la variable de tipo tabla "@TSaldoEmisionCliente"? esta variable tiene los 100 mil registros? si es así de entrada deberías de cambiarla por una tabla temporal con índices.

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que con esa tabla @TSaldoEmisionCliente traigo solo aquellos datos que requiero de otra tabla que a su vez es otra tabla temporal. Cuando mencionas índices te refieres a crearlos con ROW_NUMBER? O identificarlos como agrupados o no agrupados?

Comment: Ok, Entonces tu principal problemas son esas variables de tipo "table". Para grandes cargas de información es mejor usar tablas temporales, te dejo un link que te puede ayudar: [sqlhack](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/cuando-utilizar-las-tablas-temporales-de-sql-frente-a-las-variables-de-tabla/)

Comment: Prácticamente es lo mismo que crear una tabla normal, solo que agregas el carácter "#" al principio del nombre de la tabla, esto le indica a SQL que es una tabla temporal la cual se eliminará al terminar la sesión (lo recomendable es que la elimines cuando ya no la necesites) y al igual que una tabla "normal" puedes crear claves principales, foráneas e índices (agrupados o no agrupados) para aumentar el performance.

Comment: Entonces cuando hago uso de `DECLARE @Tabla TABLE` no estoy declarando una tabla temporal? Y por qué el uso de índices mejora el rendimiento?

Comment: Esas son **variables de tipo table** funcionan como si fueran tablas temporales, pero no, son variables. La gran diferencia de ambas (entre otras diferencias) es a la hora del manejo y carga de información, ya que como te diste cuenta el rendimiento en los querys se ve afectado.
El uso de índices mejora el rendimiento porque es una forma de decirle a sql a donde dirigirse a la hora de buscar en vez de recorrer toda la tabla, funciona más o menos como si fuese el índice de un libro.
Ambos temas son un poco extensos, te recomiendo que los investigues, ya que solo te doy pequeños ejemplos.

Comment: He revisado e implementado las tablas temporales, pero de todos modos sigue siendo muy ineficiente, de 7 min bajó a 5 min; incluso sin hacer uso de tablas temporales y modificando otras cosas de las variables ya declaradas, el tiempo es de 4 min.

Comment: Si, como te comente al principio, de entrada era el tema de las tablas temporales, y por otra parte la falta de información. Edita y envía todo tu query, desde la inserción de datos en las tablas, hasta donde se muestran los resultados para identificar los detalles de performance.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137078/discussion-between-lsanchezo-and-kevin-barrios).